# Is there any way to get syncdb to pull in models that aren't in models.py?

Tags: django, django-syncdb

I have a file filled with models embedded deep within my app and not in a models.py file or models directory.

Basically it's a file that points to tables on a legacy database, which is why I put it in a separate file.

However, now that I'm trying to set up a testing version, I need to be able to create all the tables via syncdb.

Is there any way for me to do this? Or must I create the tables manually using SQL?

Comment: You could write the models in a models.py file and include the path of the directory of this file in the `INSTALLED_APPS` parameter in the settings file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

temp_app/models.py

```
from my.deep.in.code.modelfile import model1
from my.deep.in.code.modelfile import model2
```

Add temp_app to installed apps (make sure you also have **init**.py in the dir)

Run Syncdb

Remove temp_app from installed apps

Answer (score 1):

**forehead slap time**

Okay, so this part is key: if you do import models from elsewhere in your project, not within the normal models.py files, make sure you add:

```
class Meta:
    app_label = 'foo'
```

Otherwise, the models will be ignored by syncdb!

I did try something along the lines of what Ted wrote but for some reason it wasn't until I added the `app_label` part that syncdb was able to create the models.